# Potentiometer for PWM motor controller: how to deal with a limited input range?

Tags: pwm, potentiometer

I've got a 3V DC toy motor that I'd like to convert to variable speed using a PWM circuit. I found an [$5 PWM controller](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/1803BK-Pulse-Width-Modulator-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Control-Controller-Switch-/262741580396?hash=item3d2c9e5a6c:g:4sAAAOSw2xRYPmvm) that would work. This expects a 100 K\$\Omega\$  potentiometer as its speed input.

I want to set the speed using a mechanical trigger (like on a variable-speed drill), but that means I have an input that travels only 5-10 mm. 
The potentiometers I've found are rotary (270° travel) or linear/slider (20 mm travel). If I were to use these, I'd only be able to use part of the 0-100 k\$\Omega\$ range.

How should I approach this?

- create a mechanical system to convert the trigger travel into the full range of the pot,
- is there a way to get the full rpm range out of the PWM circuit using only part of the potmeter range?
- or should I build a custom PWM circuit instead?

Comment: What range does your PWM controller expect? 0-100k? then buy a 0-200k and use only half of it.

Comment: If you want "variable speed" then you need a "once per rev" sensor. "I have an input that travels only 5-10 mm" - I don't understand the relevance given you want "variable speed". Your question is confusing.

Comment: @Andyaka: I think he means that he wants a mechanical trigger with 5-10mm travel that he uses to control the PWM with his fingers.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: correct.

Comment: A link to the PWM controller is required.

Comment: From the link, it is not clear whether you can use an external voltage or not. If this where possible, maybe you should be able to use a x2 gain op-amp to get the full range from half potentiometer.

Comment: A pdf data sheet is what I would consider the minimum pre-requisite for purchasing any component or sub assembly. Anything without one I would not consider useful or reliable.

Comment: I'm pretty certain potentiometers come in a variety of sizes and shapes and aren't limited to 20 mm travel distance.

Comment: 20 mm is the shortest I've found at a large supplier (3 out of 300 search results). Most linear potentiometers are longer.

Comment: Actually you could do what they put on Wha-Wha pedals, its a rotary pot on the inside with a cog, then a rack with teeth that turns the cog. Think of it like a rack and pinion style. Actually just google rack and pinion potentiometer and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @crowie: that's a good one. A search for 'wah potentiometer' finds lots of usable parts to build the trigger mechanism.

Comment: @Hobbes yea the good thing is you can use a very cheap pot then adjust the cog size to get the amount of travel to pot turn you need

Answer (score 1):

I would use a slider something like this; [Slider potentiometer](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cts-electrocomponents/448VB1104BDN/CT2338-ND/203887).  I think it would be easier to make a linear mechanism than a rotary one.